# How can I force electron to update rendering based on new css?

Tags: css, node.js, electron, browser-cache

I'm trying to build an electron app (my first) on Windows 10 (using Visual Studio Code and Git Bash as tools), and for some reason my app has simply stopped updating based on css changes.  In particular, I have a search box which I had been playing around with using different bootstrap form input styling.  However, when I decided to take all of that away and just put in a vanilla html form, I still get the fancy bootstrap input.

I can successfully change the html by adding more text that shows up in the app, but as long as I have a text input element, I end up with the fancy styled bootstrap input.  I tried deleting the electron cache for my app, and I then tried deleting the entire ~/AppData/Roaming/myapp directory, neither of which helped.  I then tried creating a new app entirely in a new folder, reran "npm install --save electron", copied in my html and js files (but not any other files), and tried again... and I still get the bootstrap styled form!  I have looked at solutions like the one described here ([Electron not using updated css file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37691304/electron-not-using-updated-css-file)) but without any noticeable difference.  I am at a total loss of what to do and can only imagine that either electron is hiding another cache somewhere or that somehow Visual Studio Code or Git Bash are hiding caches somewhere that are screwing me over.

Here are the only 3 files in my project:

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "author": "",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^6.0.10"
  }
}
```

main.js:

```
const electron = require('electron');
const path = require('path');
const url = require('url');

// SET ENV
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'development';

const {app, BrowserWindow, Menu} = electron;

let mainWindow;

// Listen for app to be ready
app.on('ready', function(){

  // Create new window
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({});
  mainWindowURL = url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'mainWindow.html'),
    protocol: 'file:',
    slashes:true
  });

  mainWindow.webContents.session.clearCache(function(){})

  mainWindow.loadURL(mainWindowURL, {"extraHeaders":"pragma: no-cache\n"})
  // Quit app when closed
  mainWindow.on('closed', function(){
    app.quit();
  });

  // Build menu from template
  const mainMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(mainMenuTemplate);
  // Insert menu
  Menu.setApplicationMenu(mainMenu);

  // Clear cache from any previous sessions
  //mainWindow.webContents.session.clearStorageData();
  //win.once('ready-to-show', ()=>{win.show()})
  //const win = BrowserWindow.getAllWindows()[0];
  //const ses = win.webContents.session;

  //ses.clearCache(() => {});
});



// Add developer tools option if in dev
if(process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'){
  mainMenuTemplate.push({
    label: 'Developer Tools',
    submenu:[
      {
        role: 'reload'
      },
      {
        label: 'Toggle DevTools',
        accelerator:process.platform == 'darwin' ? 'Command+I' : 'Ctrl+I',
        click(item, focusedWindow){
          focusedWindow.toggleDevTools();
        }
      }
    ]
  });
}
```

mainWindow.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Miobium</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">
  <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">-->
  <!--<link rel="script" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js">-->

  <style>
    .fullPageContainer{
    }
    #left_panel {
        background-color: white;
        height: 100vh;
        float: left;
        width: 20vw;
        border-right: 1px solid grey;
    }
    #main_panel{
        background-color: white;
        height: 100vh;
        float: right;
        width: calc(78vw - 2px);
    }
    input[type=text]{
      width: 80%;
      border: 1px solid grey;
      border-radius: 4px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="fullPageContainer">

        <div id="left_panel">
            Tags
        </div>

        <div id="main_panel">
          Search
          <form>
            <input type='text'>
          </form>
        </div>

    </div>

  <script>
    const electron = require('electron');
    const {ipcRenderer} = electron;
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I would greatly appreciate any insight you guys may have!  I am a novice with electron and am hoping there is something simple that I can do to fix this problem.  Thanks!

Comment: Inside of devtools (CTRL + SHIFT + I) is bootstrap showing up in your sources?

Comment: @ThatPurpleGuy I see "internal/bootstrap/loaders.js", "internal/bootstrap/node.js", and "internal/bootstrap/pre_execution.js".  Where are these coming from?  Can I get rid of them?

Comment: bootstrap in this sense is not bootstrap css it just means the starter boiler plate files. these are fine. what are you using to complie your sass

Comment: @ThatPurpleGuy There is no sass in my project as far as I know.

Comment: At This point, I have tried uninstalling electron from all the test projects I have made, deleted all the caches I could find, reinstalled electron and made a new project with a text input (using file names 'mainAppWindow.html' instead of 'mainWindow.html' and 'index.js' instead of 'main.js' to further try to avoid any hidden caches), and I still get the bootstrap styled input!!  This is driving me nuts.  How do I get rid of this without deleting my entire operating system?? :"(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears I have been suffering from an unbelievable coincidence, but I have now resolved the issue.

Prior to when I started having the problem, I had been trying bootstrap search bar styles.  The very last bootstrap style I tried was one which was EXACTLY the same as the material.css text input style, and I had even changed the bootstrap style all on my own to have exactly the same 'active' color as material.css uses by default.

When I took away the bootstrap to try styling on my own, nothing happened... The input stayed exactly the same.  I assumed that this obviously meant that there was a cache somewhere.  However, it turned out that material.css just had *exactly* the same style I had created with bootstrap, and material.css doesn't require you to add any special class labels to elements before styling them so I never suspected.  Removing material.css immediately fixed the problem.

Definitely the weirdest bug coincidence I have ever experienced by orders of magnitude.